# How to display two PCA graph together?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, pca

I've relatively new to R and I'm not quite sure how to achieve this. Right now I performed PCA on two different data sets using *prcomp*.

```
data1.pr <- prcomp(data1, center=TRUE, scale=TRUE)
data2.pr <- prcomp(data2, center=TRUE, scale=TRUE)
```

I used `autoplot(data1.pr, frame = TRUE)` and `autoplot(data2.pr, frame = TRUE)` to draw the graph and it shows the results for both data1 and data2:

[image][image]

Now, how do I combine these two pictures together into one plot with different groups? I searched from some answers and it seem `geom` is one such solution. However, I'm not quite sure how to achieve that with grouping. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: PC1 for data1 is not the PC1 for data2. So you may plot the PC on plots side by side but be careful if you want to use the same plot.

Comment: PC1 for `data1` is available from `data1.pr$x[, 1]`, and PC2 from `data1.pr$x[, 2]` so on. So you can use `data1.pr$x` to plot PC's for `data1`.

Comment: Like Suren said, if you're using different data to do the PCA, it's likely you are going to end up with different principal components (unless possibly if you have the same variables and are sampling from the same population). So it's not a good idea to paste both PCA's into a single *plot*. However, you could put the two plots into the same `figure`, side-by-side, either with `ggplot2` facets or using the `cowplot` package

Comment: Or using the `patchwork` package

Answer (score 0):

Use the following library to control the size(s) of your plots.

```
library(repr) 
options(repr.plot.width = 5, repr.plot.height = 4)  # To set plot size
```

Then use the following code to output your plots side by side - resulting in one plot. .  You will need to adjust the height and width (above) to get your desired results.

```
par(mfrow = c(1, 2)  )       # To combine two plots

plot(data1)
plot(data2)
```